# What is the name of variable which is declared in a nested variable scope?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scope

Consider the following Python 2 snippet written using TensorFlow

```
with tf.variable_scope('scope'):
    layer = slim.conv2d(input_tensor, 64, 7, 2, padding='SAME', scope='another_scope')
```

I am creating a `conv2d` layer within a variable scope but am also passing another variable scope name explicitly to the constructor of the `conv2d` layer.

My questions are as follows:

1. What will be the name of the variable `layer` and in which scope would this variable be defined - `scope` or `another_scope`.
2. What is the use case for allowing users to declare variables like this?
3. Is it possible to create nested variable scopes in TensorFlow? If yes, then how does it work?
4. If scope `another_scope` hasn't been created itself, would TensorFlow create this on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the variable `layer` will have its full scope as `scope/another_scope`. To me, it seems that they have provided the scope argument so that it serves as a shorthand to doing

```
with tf.variable_scope('scope'):
    with tf.variable_scope('another_scope'):
        layer = slim.conv2d(input_tensor, 64, 7, 2, padding='SAME')
```